# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\sqrt[n]{e}-1)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How would one prove that the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\sqrt[n]{e}-1)$$

diverges? The Root and Ratio test are useless here. It is also not so obvious to me how I could bound the given series by a smaller series which diverges.

A friend a mine told me that I can use the Cauchy Condensation Test and I got to this point

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\sqrt[n]{e}-1) \sim \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^n(\sqrt[2n]{e}-1)$$

but it is unclear to me how to continue from here.

Comment: Do you know the Taylor expansion for $e^x$?

Comment: @Clayton Yes, I do (but it's no obvious to me what I should do with it to solve this problem).

Comment: Clayton suggested to take advantage from the expansion $ \sqrt[n]{e}-1=1/n+O(1/n^2)$ to infer on the behaviour of the series. The harmonic series is divergent

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\sqrt[n]{e}=e^{1/n}=1+\frac{1}{n}+\cdots>1+\frac{1}{n}.$$ Thus, we have $\sqrt[n]{e}-1>\frac{1}{n}$, and now we can look at partial sums to conclude the series is divergent.

Answer (score 10):

Since
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{e}-1}{\frac{1}{n}} =1,
\end{align*}
the series is divergent.

Comment: An easy way to see it: the limit is just the definition of $\left.\frac{de^x}{dx}\right|_{x=0} = e^0 = 1$.

Answer (score 6):

The sequence given by
$$ a_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n $$
is an increasing sequence due to the AM-GM inequality and it converges to $e$. 
It follows that
$$ \sqrt[n]{e} > 1+\frac{1}{n} $$
hence the given series is divergent by comparison with the harmonic series.

Answer (score 2):

More generally,
if $a > 1$,
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\sqrt[n]{a}-1)
$
diverges.

Since
$e^x \ge 1+x$,
$\sqrt[n]{a}
=e^{\ln(a)/n}
\ge 1+\ln(a)/n
$,
so that
$\sqrt[n]{a}-1
\ge \ln(a)/n
$
and the sum of these
diverges.

Answer (score 1):

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I showed using only the limit definition and Bernoulli's Inequality that the exponential function satisfies the inequalities

> $$1+x\le e^x\le \frac{1}{1-x} \tag 1$$

where the left-hand side inequality of $(1)$ holds everywhere whereas the right-hand side inequality holds for $x<1$.  Therefore, we find that for $n>1$ and any $a>0$

$$\frac{1}{n^a}\le e^{1/n^a}-1\le \frac{1}{n^a-1} \tag 2$$

Hence, we conclude that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(e^{1/n^a}-1\right)$ converges for $a>1$ and diverges for $a\le 1$.